# CSS transition the width of a child div inside a parent div

Tags: css, width, css-transitions, parent-child, transition

I'm trying to make child div slowly spread inside of a parent div (while active) from one number of pixels to another in 5 seconds using CSS. It must be possible, right? The way I'm trying to do it it doesn't work.

```css
#parent {
  background: black;
  height: 10px; 
  width: 300px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#child{
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transition: width 5s ease-out; 
}
  
#parent:active #child{
  max-width: 290px;
  transition: max-width 5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick to change `width` or `max-width` on active state, so in transition you can specify what you want to change. In your code you defined fixed `width` and then you are changing `max-width` but that doesn't do anything because width is still the same.

```css
#parent {
  background: black;
  height: 10px; 
  width: 300px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#child{
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 10px;
  max-width: 10px;
  transition: max-width 5s ease-out; 
}
  
#parent:active #child{
  max-width: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```